# how to redirect non existent link on website back to the home page

Tags: php, html, redirect

my question is how to redirect any non existent link on my website back to the home page. For example; imagine i have a page called "pets" on my site (http://mywebsite.com/pets) if a user types in http://mywebsite.com/petsd by accident, I want the user to be redirected to the home page. Anyone know how this can be done? Thanks.

Comment: is the page `pets` an existing file ?

Comment: When you do this, please ***don't*** change the address they've entered into the address bar. If they make a very small typo for an actual page on your site, they will then be able to easily correct the typo rather than having to type it all in again.

Comment: I wouldn't even show the homepage. A decent error page that explains it is a 404 and that includes a link to the homepage is better ("Why is this showing me the homepage? I typed in 'pets'!!"). Better yet, extract the keywords from the URI and perform a search and show the results under the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `ErrorDocument 404 /index.html` in your .htaccess file

Comment: One more question thoug. How can I preserve the original typo'd link so it still appears in the URL?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) I've implemented it and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Equip the 404-page with a javascript redirect.
Make sure it is timed, so visitors can see what happened.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `mod_rewrite`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [R]
```

Comment: Unless you have the appropriate `RewriteBase` defined, this will result in an invalid redirect. It also exposes the index document, which may be undesirable. (Although an _external redirect_ is probably not the correct thing to do in this situation anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_rewrite you can handle 404 (page not found) like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [L]
```

This will preserve original link in the browser but will show your home page.