# redirect non existent links on site back to home while preserving original link

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to redirect non existent link on website back to the home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737446/how-to-redirect-non-existent-link-on-website-back-to-the-home-page)

Hello, my question is how to redirect any non existent link on my website back to the home page. For example; imagine i have a page called "pets" on my site (`http://mywebsite.com/pets`) if a user types in `http://mywebsite.com/petsd` by accident, I want the user to be redirected to the home page, yet I want the typo to remain in the URL ( `http://mywebsite.com/petsd`) i know the .htaccess part but dont know how to preserve the url query. Anyone know how this can be done? Thanks.